# Is there are any way make locals() and globals() defaultdict-like

Tags: python, variables, python-internals, locals

Is it possible to change the behaviour of `global` and `local` variables in Python at runtime?

In Python, [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) gives references to variables in the current execution scope, which is a `dict` object.

```
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

Is it possible to replace that reference returned by `locals()` to a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but keep the previous values (a copy of `locals()`) before replacing it?

I would expect this to avoid `UnboundLocalException` exceptions when using uninitialized variables and access any variable name in the execution scope (uninitialized variables would take a specified default value).

I've tried to modify the value returned by `locals()` by reassigning it to locals without success.

The same question goes for [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. `locals()` is just a *reflection* of the actual namespace used for functions.

For performance reasons, the actual namespace is an *array* and locals are not looked up by name but by index. You can't add new names to this after the fact, because the compiler has simply not accounted for more references in the array.

Note that `NameError` exceptions are thrown for missing *globals*, not locals. Local names, if not yet bound, throw an `UnboundLocalException` instead. You can't replace the `globals()` dictionary with a defaultdict either, however; the `__dict__` attribute of module objects is read-only. Even if it wasn't read-only, only the built-in `dict` type is supported due to the way names are looked up in the namespace; this is [by design](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-October/029753.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of, using [metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python), Python's tool for modifying the behaviour of the `class` statement.

Here, `DefaultDictMeta` returns an instance of `defaultdict` from its `__prepare__` method. Any class with a metaclass of `DefaultDictMeta` will therefore end up using an instance of `defaultdict` for its namespace. This means that name lookups *can't fail* in the body of `NoNameErrorsInBody`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class DefaultDictMeta(type):
    def __prepare__(name, bases, default=None, **kwargs):
        return defaultdict(lambda: default)

    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct, **kwargs):
        # swallow keyword arguments
        return super().__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct, **kwargs):
        # swallow keyword arguments
        pass

class NoNameErrorsInBody(metaclass=DefaultDictMeta, default=2):
    x = y + 3  # y is not defined


>>> NoNameErrorsInBody.x
5
```

It goes without saying that **you should never do this** in real-world code. I'm only demonstrating it for a bit of fun. (Imagine trying to debug code which doesn't tell you when you use an invalid name. It'd be awful, like, I dunno, Javascript or something.)